# Need help calculating volume $1/(4+x^2)$ about y-axis.

Tags: calculus

> I need help calculating the volume of $\frac{1}{4+x^2}$ about the *y-axis* with $0 \leq x \leq 2$

Normally what I do when I encounter this problem is write find the inverse function which is $\sqrt{1/x-4}$. Then I recalculate the bounds which now are $1/8 \leq x \leq 1/4$.

Then I use the formula for volume by revolution about the $x$-axis as we just inverted the function. 
$V=\pi \int_{1/8}^{1/4}\sqrt{1/x-4}^2 dx = \pi (\ln(2)-1/2)$.
Which is not the correct answer, the solution is $\pi \ln(2)$.

After taking a closer look at the graph, of the inverted function $\sqrt{1/x-4}^2$ I see that a part is left out if I use the bounds $1/8 \leq x \leq 1/4$. It leaves out the part from $0$ to $1/8.$ 
So I tried again, this time my formula became 
$V=\pi \int_{1/8}^{1/4}\sqrt{1/x-4}^2 dx + \pi \int_0^{1/8}\sqrt{1/x-4}^2 dx$ But the second integral does not converge, I am at a loss on how to reach the correct volume.

Comment: Do you know shell method?

Comment: $V=2\pi \int_{x_1}^{x_2}xy \ dx$

Comment: I just researched the shell method, it should indeed give me the correct answer but we were instructed to use the disk method as we have not yet learned on how to integrate $x/(4+x^2)$.

Comment: Integrating $x/(4+x^2)$ can be done with $u$-substitution

Comment: Alright. So you split your graph in two parts. The first part you have integrated correctly already. For the second part try using volume of a cylinder.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to work the second part out by using the formula of a cylinder the $- \frac{1}{2}\pi$ from the first part cancels out by the found volume of the cylinder which is $ \frac{1}{2}\pi$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the picture and you'll instantly see what's wrong.

You wrote "the volume of $\frac 1 {4+x^2}$ about the $y$-axis". That isn't really a well-formed phrase. Perhaps an exercise asked for the volume resulting from revolving the region **below** the curve $y=\dfrac 1 {4+x^2}$ about the $y$-axis.

And **below** means it must include everything between the $x$-axis and that curve. You excluded much of that, including only the part above $y=1/8.$

You could write $x = \begin{cases} \sqrt{1/y-4} & \text{if } 1/8 \le y \le 1/4, \\[6pt] 2 & \text{if } 0 \le y < 1/4. \end{cases}$

Then proceed as you did and you should get the right answer.

Alternatively, you could use shells rather than disks and integrate with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $2.$

Comment: Thank you for this intuitive explanation, this made me realize that I should indeed integrate the second part as $x=2$ instead of $x = \sqrt{1/x-4}$ as the function is just a straight line below $1/8$.